# Panorama animation is broken when removing ApplicationBar or changing its visibility or opacity

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have 3 panorama items, and I would like only the 1st to have an app bar.

So I started to implement removing the app bar for the other panorama items.

What I did was to handle `SelectionChanged` event and based on `Panorama.SelectedIndex` hide the application bar:

```
this.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = this.Panorama.SelectedIndex == 0;
```

When swiping to the 2nd item, the usual panorama animation does not work anymore, the transition animation is gone, it's sudden.

Instead of changing `IsVisible`, I also tried with the same result:

- remove app bar `this.ApplicationBar = null`
- set opacity to zero `this.ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0`

What's interesting is that animation is broken even if changing opacity to let's say 0.5

My feeling is that layout change event in the app bar generate this Panorama broken behavior.

I haven't yet been able to find a solution.

Comment: you can achieve it very easy if you use pivot

Comment: probably, because in a pivot, the transition is sudden. I need the panorama.

Comment: that's interesting! it looks like it works, can you please explain why? I don't understand how it even works. Within a StackPanel, I didn't think Panorama will stretch vertically to occupy whole screen.

Comment: for example button have only one content, but if you put a stackpanel in it, you can do what ever you want

Comment: I don't understand why StackPanel doesn't affect the transition animation problem, while having the Panorama in a Grid does

Answer (score 2):

put the whole panorama in а stackpanel

```
<StackPanel>
<phone:Panorama Title="my application">
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="first item"/>
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="second item" Tap="OnPanoramaItemTap"/>
</phone:Panorama Title="my application">
</StackPanel>


 private void OnPanoramaItemTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

It's just an idea, but it's working, i hope it's good for your case

Comment: Thanks but, I still don't understand how does a StackPanel solve this issue